# IF statement t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

have table with columns : `number1,number2,number3`

Have Query in procedure : `SELECT number1,number2,number3 FROM myTbl`

, now want check

```
if number2 < number1 and number1 < number3 print 'OK'`
```

How do it ? I cant write select for it

Comment: What have your tried ? Show your query please

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you only need these values for a single row? Or do you need a select statement? I fear if I try to answer this question you'll just come back and say "oh but I need it differently..."

Comment: I edit question , please read again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem a bit unclear, but if you want print on condition, try this

```
if exists (SELECT * FROM myTbl where number2 < number1 and number1 < number3)
    print 'Ok'
```

Answer (score 3):

if you need select:

```
SELECT number1, number2, number3
FROM YourTable
WHERE
  number2 < number1 
  AND number1 < number3
```

or

```
SELECT 
  number1, number2, number3,
  CASE WHEN number2 < number1 AND number1 < number3 THEN 'OK' ELSE '' END AS Res
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
declare @test int;
select @test = case when number2<number1 and number1<number3 then 1 else 0 end
       from test1 where id=3;
if @test = 1 then   print 'OK'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64ca3/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
if @number2 < @number1 and @number1 < @number3
Begin
    Print 'OK'
End
```

Or this

```
Select CASE WHEN ( @number2 < @number1 and @number1 < @number3THEN expression1) 
Then 'OK' Else '' End
```

Comment: I have Query : SELECT number1,number2,number3 FROM myTbl , now want check if number2 < number1 and number1 < number3 print 'OK'

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
DECLARE @number1 int
DECLARE @number2 int
DECLARE @number3 int

SELECT 
    @number1 = number1,
    @number2 = number2,
    @number3 = number3
FROM myTbl
WHERE (some condition to get only row)

IF (@number2 < @number1 and @number1 < @number3)
BEGIN
    print 'OK'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ID int = '' --im assuming you have some sort of ID and multiple rows in the table
declare @num1 int = (select number1 from mytable where [ID] = @ID)
declare @num2 int = (select number2 from mytable where [ID] = @ID)
declare @num3 int = (select number2 from mytable where [ID] = @ID)

IF @num2 < @num1 AND @num1 < @num3
begin
SELECT 'OK'
PRINT 'OK'
end

ELSE
begin
SELECT'OK'
PRINT 'OK'
END
```